# How to build grouped top down forecast?

Tags: r, forecasting, fable-r

*Edited Version to provide a better understanding of the problem:*

Summary of the case:

I have a dataset which has several levels (line, main group, subgroup and products) which are allocated to different countries.

I want to build an aggregated forecast based on the top down approach to find the best aggregation level for my forecast.

Therefore, I build a tsibble which I want to aggregate. Using the `aggregate_key()` can only build one parent/child relation (e.g. main group/product), but I have to consider all relationships to find the best aggregation level.

So my first question: Can I implement a loop which runs through all possible levels or do I have to run all levels individually ?

Second, I need to forecast in every country for it's own. While I can simply build a grouped structure within the bottom up approach (`aggregate_key(subgroup/product)*country`) , this does not work out for the top down (as I show in my reprex below).

So my second question: Is it possible to do the grouping or do I have to forecast each country individually?

```
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                  date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-1-1"), as.Date("2020-1-20"), "day"),
                  country = rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                  line=sample(1:4,n, replace=TRUE),
                  main_group=sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE),
                  subgroup=sample(1:10,n, replace=TRUE),
                  product=sample(1:20),
                  sales=sample(281:300)) 


dat_tsibble = dat %>%as_tsibble(key = c(product, country),
                                            index = date)

dat_aggregated = dat_tsibble %>% 
        aggregate_key((subgroup/product)*country,
                      sales= sum(sales))


fit <- dat_aggregated %>%
        model(base = ETS(sales)) %>%
        reconcile(
                td = top_down(base)
        )


fc = fit %>% forecast(h="30 day")
```

I know that this df is not able to produce any forecast, but the error message is the same:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Pve.png)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please create a [reprex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what you want exactly. Your question is lacking details. Fable can handle several hierarchies and groups and can handle it top down. See the info in [chapter 11](https://otexts.com/fpp3/hierarchical.html) sections 11.1 and 11.2 from Forecasting: principles and practice 3rd edition.

Comment: I hope it is much clearer now @phiver

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It is a good practice to add error messages and codes as text, not image to be easily assessible and enhances the chances of getting useful answers. I see also you have two questions... none of them specifically related to the error message (so three questions?)... are not better to split into different posts to enable focused discussion? But a note: assure some consistency among text/question and code... which are the levels and loops mentioned in the first question in the code, for example? Should not be your question just about the error message?